# Pipenv TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, locking packages

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Hello everyone I'm new to python, pip, and virtual environments:

Im trying to install pygments in this way:

I moved to the directory of the project:

then :

```
pipenv install pygments
```

the package is being installed, but I think there is an issue in locking the packages.

the result is below :

```
Installing pygments...
Collecting pygments
Using cached          
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.2.0
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/ee/b6e02dc6529e82b75bb06823ff7 
 005b141037cb1416b10c6f00fc419dca/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Adding pygments to Pipfile's [packages]...
Pipfile.lock (a65489) out of date, updating to (688642)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 402, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-              
 packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 250, in actually_resolve_deps
      req = Requirement.from_line(dep)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-            
 packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 
704, in from_line
    line, extras = _strip_extras(line)
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Try removing the lock file and running `Pipenv` again.

Comment: I tried the first thing and it didn't work

Comment: Can you post your Pipfile?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I have had this problem once, it seems that this problem will occur in Python3.6.

my Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pyinstaller = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: I re installed pipenv for ths directory and it worked.

Comment: I may find a way to solve this problem.
If your pip version is 18.1, then this error will occur, because pipenv does not support the 18.1 version of pip, so you need to execute `pip install "pip==18.0" `to reduce the pip version to 18.0. Normal use of pipenv.

Comment: pipenv run pip install pip==18.0